# How can I GET external data and combine it with my current view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a view that I want to use to pull Model data + get data from an external API. Using the same URL path to get database data + external API data, as they are both relatively connected in terms of business logic.

This is how I tried implementing it:

```
class BucketList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = BucketListSerializer
    filter_backends = [OwnerOrUserFilterBackend]
    queryset = Bucket.objects.all()

    # I use a field in my model as part of my GET request
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        bucket_symbols = Bucket.objects.only('stock_list')
        symbols_unicode = (','.join(map(str, bucket_symbols)))
        postgrest_urls = f"http://localhost:3000/rpc/bucketreturn?p_stocks=%7B{symbols_unicode}%7D"
        response = requests.get(postgrest_urls, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json()
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The idea of `def get()`, is to extract every `stock_list` field in objects, and feed that into my other API on localhost. To clarify, I want every `stock_list` in object passed into my get `requests` and returned, for each object.

However I keep getting undefined errors in my JSON response.

How can I properly implement a two-in-one view solution for my view, I still want to keep my original `queryset = Bucket.objects.all()` in my view.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful informaton.

Comment: if you have problem with `undefined errors in my JSON response.` then show it in question. It seems your problem is only `requests` and it has nothing to do direclty with `django` and `view`.

Comment: maybe create normal `url` with normal chars instead of `%7B` `%7D` because `requests` may try to convert  `%7B` `%7D` to another code with `%` and it will create wrong url -like `%% %7 %B` instead of expected `%7B`.

Comment: Hey, so the problem originates from my `get` method inside my class. The JSON response then gets confused because I'm passing wrong data for the f-string.